# Using SMB Trying to Delete File After Copy

Tags: java, smb

I get the following error on the delete method:

jcifs.smb.SmbException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

How can I make sure there is not a lock on the file so it can be deleted?

My code:

```
try{

   NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(attachmentRoot_DOMAIN,attachmentRoot_ID,attachmentRoot_PW);
   NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth2 = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(drawings_DOMAIN,drawings_ID,drawings_PW);

   SmbFile fromfile = new SmbFile("smb:" + dldf.getDldrawingfile(), auth, SmbFile.FILE_SHARE_READ|SmbFile.FILE_SHARE_WRITE|SmbFile.FILE_SHARE_DELETE);

   SmbFile toFile = new SmbFile(drawings_PATH + new DrawingNumberSubDirectory(dldf.getDrawingnumber()).getDrawingnumbersubdirectory() + "/" + dldf.getShortfilename() + ".PDF", auth2);
   fromfile.copyTo(toFile);


   fromfile.delete();
   }
   catch(Exception e){
       System.out.println("DocsVisionDrawingList: AcrobatRotateAndMerge_2: " + e);
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

The SMB protocol does not give you this info.
What you can do is to mark the file for deletion by using the `delete on close` bit in the create request, this is a SMB capability.

I do not know if the jCifs has this capability , there are several java SMB clients that supporting this issue. (even supporting not only SMBv1)

- You can check the [visuality systems jNQ product](http://visualitynq.com/products/jnq-java-smb-client) - this is commercial product.

Comment: @Elid Cohen can you please elaborate on the statement you made 'delete on close' bit? I looked for this property in SmbFile but could not find it.

Comment: I wrote that i do not know if the jCIFS support this property.
I know that in the SMB protocol you have this option.

Comment: If you cannot open the file due to an exclusive lock, you will not be able to set this bit also.